# Is there a DM-scripting command to control second image shift coils on JEOL microscopes?

Tags: dm-script

DM scripting have many commands to control deflectors such as beam shift, beam tilt, image shift and projector shift. On the system of a JEOL microscope, however, the command for "image shift" can only access to the 1st image shift coils (i.e., probably upper deflection coils of the doulble deflection coils system). Although the 2nd image shift coils (i.e., lower deflection coils) can be accessed from the JEOL software, I need to control it from Gatan systems.

Does anybody know if there is a DM scripting command to access the 2nd image shift coils on JEOL microscopes?

I will be really grateful, if you share some wisdom to control it.

Comment: Do JEOL microscopes provide a way of setting these values by any programmable route? (Script language, command-line parameter, ...) ? If so, there might be work-arounds to your problem, but I know too little about JEOL machines to have an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

There are no EMControl script commands outside the documented ones (GMS 3.3).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. Although I have not carefully checked the document of GMS 3.3 yet, probably the command which I need is not prepared in EMControl command series. Instead of DM scripting, JEOL provides us a MATLAB-based scripting language for JEOL microscoeps, in which can access to the 2nd image shift coils. So if GMS can control the MATALB environment installed on other PC, the controlling of the 2nd image shift coils of JEOL microscopes from GMS may be able. But, I have no good idea to acheive it.

Comment: @kachigusa Maybe you can post that as a separate question here. Am I right in thinking that matlab scripts can be called via the command prompt? If so, one can use the DM script command 'LaunchExternalProcess' to run these scripts. By being creative with writing things to text-files one can make GMS "communicate" like this. Such a solution has f.e. already been used using VisualBasic scripts to access some functionality on FEI machines not directly accessible otherwise. It is a bit of a "hack" but one can get things working.

Comment: I'm sorry for my delayed response. Thank you very much for your quite useful advices. I feel your suggestion to use the DM script command 'Launch External Process' is quite reasonable for my purpose. If I can make a external executable file located on the MATLAB PC which can control 2nd image shift coils of JEOL microscopes, and GMS is able to contol the external executable file, a GMS system can access to 2nd image shift coils indirectly, right?

Comment: I don't know the detail because it is not documentated officially, but a DLL file to externaly control a JEOL microscope is prepared by JEOL.  And, probably, we can make a external program using the DLL file, by VisualBasic, C++, C# etc.. If I try this hack, I need the help of JEOL's technitians, although JEOL may not support it officially. Did you mean this kind of hack in your previous comment about the "hack" by VisualBasic scripts for FEI microscopes?

Comment: @kachigusa No, I just meant I know that a VBScript + LaunchExternalApplication() solution has been successfully done on FEI machines, using files written to hard drive as "buffer" between the two.  As for the JEOL DLL: This is likely not going to work, because DM is already communicating via this/such a DLL and you most likely can not have concurring access to the same COM object. I know this to be the case for the microscope communication API of FEI machines where I wanted to do this something like this with the Gatan SDK a few years back.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. In the FEI machines case you mentioned, it have succeed that DM communicates with the microscope (or FEI software?)  through a "buffer" file, right? Is it like a following procedure?  Firstly DM makes a buffer file containing some parameter values. Next, the microscope system (which is checking whether or not both the buffer file and appropriate parameters are exist) reads the file and executing a prepared process corresponding by using loaded parameters. Then, repeating this cycle. Is this correct?  (I'm really sorry for bothering you.)

Comment: Concerning the DLL for the external communication to a microscope, I'm planning to make a executable file for controlling a microscope function, and try to execute the created executable file by using DM + LaunchExternalApplication() . I am very afraid of asking this kind of basic question but, is the COM object accessed concurrently even in this case? In your (or another expert's?) idea using Gatan SDK, did you try to access the COM object directly from a DM system (and your homemade DM function to control a microscope function, made by Gatan SDK)?

Comment: @kachigusa Yes to your first comment (But maybe start a new question-post here on this topic, please. The comments here are not the right place.) And yes, to your second command as well. The DLL created by the SDK was attempting to connect the the COM object which DM already connected to as well - hence it didn't work. But if you can, certainly try it.

Comment: @kachigusa Did you manage to access your microscope via MatLab executable and command prompt? If you do (or don't), please let me know. it's good to know what works and what doesn't if others are asking.